# 2 Samuel 11:14 In what form of Hebrew did David write in?

Tags: hebrew, 2-samuel

In what form of Hebrew did David write in 2 Samuel 11:14?

> 14 In the morning **David wrote a letter** to Joab and sent it by the
> hand of Uriah.

Did David use modern alef-beit אָלֶף־בֵּית or did he use the older Paleo-Hebrew alphabet.

Comment: It is very likely David used the Paleo-Hebrew alphabet - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Hebrew_writings for a description of the writing styles in ancient times.

Answer (score 5):

**Hebrew writing inscriptions near the time of David**

He would have used paleo-Hebrew handwriting.  Here are a few inscriptions that would have handwriting near the time of David.

1. **[Tel Dan stele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Dan_stele)**

[image]

2. **[The Mesha Stele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesha_Stele)**, also known as the **Moabite Stone**

After getting the paleo-Hebrew handwriting down, you can read all but one word on the stele with a BDB Hebrew lexicon.  So, Moab's language wasn't that different.

[This image is too large to display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesha_Stele#/media/File:Mesha_Stele_drawing.png).

3. **[Siloam inscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siloam_inscription)**

[This image s too large to display](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Siloam_Inscription_Squeeze.tif/lossy-page1-2560px-Siloam_Inscription_Squeeze.tif.jpg)

Comment: thank you for your contribution!